# How to use PHP Simple DOM Parser for a div that has an id and class?

Tags: php, dom

What code would I would use to get the information a div that contains both an id and a class?
For example how would I use PHP Simple DOM Parser to view this div?

```
<div id="the-id" class="the-class">
```

I know that I use `$html->find('div[id=the-id]', 0);` if there is only an id in the div, but how do I parse a div with a class and id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you just expand the css-like selector?

I haven't tested, but I think any one of the following should produce the result you want.

```
$html->find('div.the-class[id=the-id]', 0);
$html->find('div.the-class#the-id', 0);
$html->find('div[id=the-id][class=the-class]', 0); // only if that's the only
$html->find('div[id=the-id][class~=the-class]', 0); // even if there's multiple classes
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple dom parser query strings work just like css.  To find divs with id "the-id", use `->find('div#the-id')`.  Presumably, you have unique IDs, so that's all you need.

If you really want, you can use `->find('div#the-id.the-class')`, but it's generally unnecessary to be that specific.

Answer (score 0):

```
$html->find('#the-id .the-class', 0);
//or
$html->find('[id=the-id] [class=the-class]', 0);
```

Seperate elements by spaces.

```
// Find all <li> in <ul>
$es = $html->find('ul li');

// Find Nested <div> tags
$es = $html->find('div div div');

// Find all <td> in <table> which class=hello
$es = $html->find('table.hello td');

// Find all td tags with attribite align=center in table tags
$es = $html->find(''table td[align=center]');

// Find all <li> in <ul>
foreach($html->find('ul') as $ul)
{
       foreach($ul->find('li') as $li)
       {
             // do something...
       }
}

// Find first <li> in first <ul>
$e = $html->find('ul', 0)->find('li', 0);
```

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Answer (score -2):

Are you sure you want to do this in php? Doing this in javascript is dead easy

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("the-class");
for (var element in elements)
{
    var id = element.getAttribute("id");
}
```

alternatively...

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var element in elements)
{
    var id = element.getAttribute("id");
    var class_name = element.get.Attribute("class");
}
```